# (Angular) Clicking on a button highlights another button because I'm changing a value in an array. Why?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, click

So I'm trying to make a website using Angular and have come across a very peculiar bug.
Basically I have an *ngFor div that creates 12 buttons.

```
<div *ngFor = "let color of colors; let i = index" style = "display: inline;">
  <button (click) = "toggleTrue(i)" id = "{{i}}" class = "coloredButton">
  </button>
</div>
```

When a button is clicked then it should highlight the button and then change a value in an array within my component like so.

```
toggleTrue(id: number){
    this.colors[id] = !this.colors[id];
    var button = document.getElementById(id.toString());
    if(this.colors[id] === true){
      button.style.border = "10px";
      button.style.borderColor = "white";
      button.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    }
    else{
      button.style.borderStyle = "none";
    }
}
```

However for some reason whenever I click a button it highlights the button next to it and if I click it twice more than it will highlight a button two buttons away for some reason, click it twice more and it'll highlight a button three buttons away, etc. It's not highlighting the right button, but the id it passes through to the function is correct, I checked using console.log(id).

I've messed around a bit (taking out classes and lines and whatnot) and I've isolated the problem to this line.

```
this.colors[id] = !this.colors[id];
```

If I remove this then everything works fine (except of course I can't edit the value of the array anymore). This is proven further when I remove the click function of my buttons and the default highlight for buttons correctly highlights the right button.
Can anyone please help me out and tell me why it's not highlighting correctly? Any help would be appreciated.
If you're curious I created the array earlier within the component using colors = [] and it's an array of booleans that I filled within the constructor using a basic for loop.

Comment: what is the value of your colors array?

Comment: All the values are set to false in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-brook-wn3q0?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Here is a sandbox with a solution.
Essentially you want to keep styling in the template through the use of NgClass or NgStyle
and use the component just for changing state, avoid accessing the DOM directly due to lifecycle problems.

Typescript

```
export class AppComponent {
  colors: boolean[];

  constructor() {
    this.colors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.colors.push(false);
    }
  }

  toggleTrue(id: number) {
    this.colors[id] = !this.colors[id];
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let color of colors; index as i">
    <button
      (click)="toggleTrue($event, i)"
      id="{{i}}"
      [ngClass]="{'active':colors[i]==true}"
    >
      button
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  color: red;
}

.inactive {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, the other person who answered this question didn't use the [ngClass] to activate the button styling, thats why it wasn't working thanks a lot kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some changes in your code. Firs in your HTML:

```
<button *ngFor="let color of colors; let i = index" (click) = "toggleTrue(i)" class = "coloredButton" [class.active]="color"> {{i}} < /button>
```

You noticed about [class.active]="color" this sentence verify if color is true the button will have the active class

```
.active {
  border: 10px solid white;
}
```

I don't know how you generate colors array but I assumed somethings and also change your function in the class component

```
colors = new Array(10).fill(false);

toggleTrue(index: number) {
  this.colors[index] = !this.colors[index]
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate you helping me tidy up my code, the current issue still persists.